# alpakka jms client acknowledgement mode delivery guarantee

Tags: apache-kafka, jms, akka-stream, alpakka

I have an alpakka JMS source -> kafka sink kind of a flow. I'm looking at the alpakka jms consumer documentation and trying to figure out what kind of delivery guarantees this gives me.

From https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/jms/consumer.html

```
val result: Future[immutable.Seq[javax.jms.Message]] =
  jmsSource
    .take(msgsIn.size)
    .map { ackEnvelope =>
      ackEnvelope.acknowledge()
      ackEnvelope.message
    }
    .runWith(Sink.seq)
```

I'm hoping that the way this actually works is that messages will only be ack'ed once the sinking succeeds (for at-least-once delivery guarantees), but I can't rely on wishful thinking.

Given that alpakka does not seem to utilize any kind of own state that persists across restarts, I can't think how I'd be able to get exactly-once guarantees [a'la flink](https://flink.apache.org/features/2018/03/01/end-to-end-exactly-once-apache-flink.html) here, but can I at least count on at-least-once, or would I have to (*somehow*) ack in a map of a kafka producer flexiFlow (https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka-kafka/current/producer.html#producer-as-a-flow)

Thanks,
Fil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that stream, the ack will happen before messages are added to the materialized sequence and before `result` becomes available for you to do anything (i.e. the `Future` completes).  It therefore would be `at-most-once`.

To delay the ack until some processing has succeeded, the easiest approach is to keep what you're doing with the messages in the flow rather than materialize a future.  The Alpakka Kafka producer supports a pass-through element which could be the JMS message:

```scala
val topic: String = ???

def javaxMessageToKafkaMessage[Key, Value](
  ae: AckEnvelope,
  kafkaKeyFor: javax.jms.Message => Key,
  kafkaValueFor: javax.jms.Message => Value
): ProducerMessage.Envelope[Key, Value, javax.jms.Message] = {
  val key = kafkaKeyFor(ae.message)
  val value = kafkaValueFor(ae.message)
  ProducerMessage.single(new ProducerRecord(topic, key, value), ae)
}

// types K and V are unspecified...
jmsSource
  .map(
    javaxMessageToKafkaMessage[K, V](
      _,
      { _ => ??? },
      { _ => ??? }
    )
  )
  .via(Producer.flexiFlow(producerSettings))
  .to(
    Sink.foreach { results =>
      val msg = results.passThrough
      msg.acknowledge()
    }
  )(Keep.both)
```

`run`ning this stream will materialize as a tuple of a `JmsConsumerControl` with a `Future[Done]`.  Not being familiar with JMS, I don't know how a `shutdown` of the consumer control would interact with the acks.